# Bash subshell input with variable number of subshells

Tags: bash, io-redirection, subshell

I want to `grep` lines from a variable number of log files and connect their outputs with `paste`. If I had a fixed number of outputs, I could do it thus:

```
paste <(grep $PATTERN $FILE1) <(grep $PATTERN $FILE2)
```

But is there a way to do this with a variable number of input files? I want to write a shell script whose arguments are the input files. The shell script should `paste` the grepped lines from ALL of them.

Comment: Grep will accept a list of files, perhaps a wildcard would do what you need? you can append to a file using the pipe append `>>` so delete the output, then run your greps in a loop each appending to the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explicit named pipes, instead of process substitution.

```
pipes=()
for f in "$FILE1" "$FILE2" "$FILE3"; do
    n="$(mktemp)"  # Or some other command to create a temporary name
    mkfifo "$n"
    pipes+=( "$n" )
    grep "$PATTERN" "$f" > "$n" &
done

paste "${pipes[@]}"
rm  "${pipes[@]}"   # When done with them
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by combining `find` command to list the files and piping its output to grep usings `xargs` to ensure grep is applied on each file listed in `find` command

```
$ find /dir/containing/files -name "file.*" | xargs grep $PATTERN
```

Comment: This doesn't use the output of each `grep` as a input file for `paste`, though.